# How to access redshift regional endpoint from within a restricted VPC?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I need to access Redshift regional endpoint programmatically to restore a table using boto3 APIs. My code is inside a lambda function bound to a restricted subnet (not NATs). 
So for accessing AWS services inside this lambda like Glue and Athena I use VPC endpoints but there is no VPC endpoint for Redshift and I cannot run my boto3 API (getting "Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://redshift.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"). 
I believe the only way to make this work is to route traffic to a NAT instance/gateway. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that there is no VPC Endpoint available for Amazon Redshift. Any API calls will need to be made via the Internet.

This could be accomplished by installing a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet of your VPC.

An alternative approach would be to **create an additional AWS Lambda function** that is *not* associated with your VPC. This means that it will have access to the Internet (but not the VPC).

Your existing Lambda function could call the 'external' Lambda function, which would then call Amazon Redshift. However, this would require an **API Gateway and a VPC Endpoint for API Gateway** because there is no VPC Endpoint for Lambda.

See a similar discussion on Reddit: [Access Lambda service from Lambda in a VPC : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/b7gld5/access_lambda_service_from_lambda_in_a_vpc/)

You could also go via Amazon SNS and a VPC Endpoint for SNS, with SNS then triggering the Lambda function (but you would not receive a 'return signal' when it has completed).

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein. It makes sense. So while my Redshift cluster is in that restricted subnet (no public internet access) I am wondering how the Redshift maintenance completes during the maintenance window? Doesn't the maintenance need public internet access?

Comment: Management and maintenance of the Amazon Redshift cluster is performed from a back-end "control plane" that does not use the VPC and does not require Internet connectivity.